# Rename all .htaccess files on server

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

On my localhost I have enabled htaccess evaluation in apache2.conf and now I keep getting `500 (Internal Server Error)`.

I think I have some faulty .htaccess files that not being evaluated caused no issues before, but now are causing the error. I used `find /var/www/ -name ".htaccess" -print` to find the files, but they are too many.

For now, I would like to rename ALL `.htaccess` files to `old.htaccess` wherever they are. Using: `rename  .htaccess old.htaccess` results in this error in terminal:
`syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "."`.

Wrapping the filenames like `rename ".htaccess" "old.htaccess"` produces the same error.

What is the correct command to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rename` doesn't work that way; you need to specify a PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) pattern and replacement to work with it.

For this purpose, `mv` is enough; a fast way to rename all the `.htaccess` files in `/var/www` would be to use `find` itself:

```
find /var/www -type f -name '.htaccess' -execdir mv {} old.htaccess \;
```

Sample output on a test hierarchy:

```
user@debian ~/tmp % tree -a
.
├── 1
│   └── .htaccess
├── 2
│   └── .htaccess
└── 3
    └── .htaccess

3 directories, 3 files
user@debian ~/tmp % find . -type f -name '.htaccess' -execdir mv {} old.htaccess \;       
user@debian ~/tmp % tree -a
.
├── 1
│   └── old.htaccess
├── 2
│   └── old.htaccess
└── 3
    └── old.htaccess

3 directories, 3 files
```